# EF Code First - How do you specify foreign key name for child object table used by different type of parents

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I've got some objects that look like this:

```
abstract public class Field
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Ordinal { get; set; }
}

[Table("DropDownField")]
public class DropDownField : Field
{
    public virtual List<FieldOption> Options { get; set; }
}

[Table("RadioButtonField")]
public class RadioButtonField : Field
{
    public virtual List<FieldOption> Options { get; set; }
}

public class FieldOption
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In my database, it ends up creating the a FieldOptions table using Code First. However, it creates the following columns:

- Id
- Name
- Value
- DropDownField_Id
- RadioButtonField_Id

What I'd like to see is just one Field_Id in this table since the Id of a field has to be unique across the different types of fields.

Is there a way to do this? I've done some searching but I must not know the right search terms to use to find the answer.

Comment: well in your case, you may try to put the list on the base class.

Comment: I could do that, but there are other field types (TextBoxField for example) that don't need to include the Options. I just didn't include them in the example.

Answer (score 0):

imho, what you want, from a relational database point of view, is a column (Option.FieldId) being a foreign key to 2 tables DropDownField and RadioButtonField.

That is whenever you insert an option, FieldId must reference an existing DropDownField AND an existing RadioButtonField.

That is at least weird.

I don't think this can/should be achieved.

Comment: Right, that would be weird, but the Option.FieldId, could potentially reference the Id of the Field table. In the current database structure, three tables are created: Field, DropDownField, and RadioButtonField. Any Id in the DropDownField or RadioButtonField has a corresponding Id in the Field table. The other tables just store any unique values.

Comment: honestly, I search quite a long time an "elegant" solution to this problem and I even keep it in a queue in my mind. But I stop considering it as a "blocking" question when I faced the DBA point of view, particularly the integrity constraints.